# How to properly render at half of the display refresh rate (frame skipping)?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, webgl, requestanimationframe

How to implement frame skipping when using `requestAnimationFrame`?

Naive approach would be to execute my rendering code every second frame, but I fear that it would break if my code is actually taking too long to execute and exceeds frame budget time.

`requestAnimationFrame` *usually* executes at 60 Hz, but the rate can be actually any value, e.g. 75 Hz, 120 Hz or 144 Hz. I would like to render at half of the supported display refresh rate, not faster.

Quote from MDN:

> The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation.

Comment: what's wrong with skipping every other frame? not really sure what you're asking. not sure what to think would break.

Comment: @gman I would like to render at 30 FPS when a browser couldn't handle 60 FPS and for example is rendering at 45 FPS. I'm not sure if skipping every other frame would achieve exactly that.